# MySQL regular expression return string instead of Y/N

Tags: mysql, regex

Is it possible to do regular expression in MySQL like other languages?

I know there exist [RLIKE or REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html), but it seems like they only return you yes or no instead of the match. Or they do have this functionality, can anyone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use User Defined Functions (UDFs), MySQL does only give you yes/no answers. For MySQL there are good UDFs, for example https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg. If you include that, you have access to RegExps just like in PHP.